# Find m elements in n arrays by picking at most 1 element out of each of the n arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, max-flow

I have `n` arrays, each of them contain an arbitrary amount of integers. No duplicates are possible within an array (`[1,1,2]` can't be one of the `n` arrays).

I also have an integer array of size `m` which is filled with integers from `1` to `m` (value_of_an_array_entry = array_index+1). Example: `m = 4`, the appropriate array is `[1,2,3,4]`.

**My question:**

For given `n` and `m`, is it possible to find every element in the `m` array by picking at most 1 element out of each of the `n` arrays?

An Example:

`n = 3, m = 3,`

The `n` arrays: `[1]`, `[1, 2]`, `[2, 3]`

Output should be: `Yes`

(because we can find every element in the `m` array by picking at most 1 element out of each of the `n` arrays. Look at the `n` arrays and pick `1` from the first array, `2` from the second and `3` from the third array.)

This is an interview question, I received a hint to think about the Max flow problem (I don't see how this helps me).

Comment: Can `n = [5,7] [8,9] [10,15] ... m = [1,2,3,4]` happen? Or is there a condition that does not allow the n and m arrays to be this different? IIRC the max flow algorithm has to do with graphs, so the n-array might be a node. You pick only 1 edge from there to get to your destination.

Comment: So what about the coding aspect of the problem? Maybe you wrote some code that helps you out of it??

Comment: @hamena314 such `n` arrays are possible.

Comment: @ShayHaned It's difficult to write code when I can't even come up with a general solution for the problem on paper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can build a graph like this: The graph is divided into the left part and the right part. The left part contains `n` vertices which represent the `n` arrays. The right part contains `m` vertices which represent the `m` numbers.

[image]

Then we consider these `n` arrays. If element `k` is contained in the `i`-th array, we draw an edge between the `i`-th vertex from the left and the `k`-th vertex from the right. Our goal is to choose `m` edges, so that each of the `m` vertices on the right is covered by the `m` edges exactly once, and the vertices on the left is covered at most once. This is a bipartite graph maximum matching problem, which can be solved by many algorithms, including max flow.

Comment: Interesting approach, works on paper, I'll try implementing it.

Comment: Added a picture - please let me know if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think a recursive method should do it.

- If m is an empty list, PASS
- Otherwise, look for members of m containing the first element of m

  - if none found: FAIL
  - for each one found:

    - this member of m is part of a PASS if there is a PASS for `m' = tail(m)` and  `n' = other members of (n)`

I haven't tested this, but:

```
public boolean check(List<Integer> m, List<List<Integer>> n) {
    if (m.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }

    int head = head(m);
    List<Integer> tail = tail(m);

    for (List<Integer> nMember : n) {
        if (nMember.contains(head) && check(tail, nMinus(n, nMember))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Assumed methods:

- `head()` returns the first element of the passed list.
- `tail()` returns the passed list with the first element removed.
- `nMinus()` returns a view or copy of `n` with `nMember` removed. It should not modify `n`.

You should use immutable collections, or at least treat them as immutable. Guava provides classes that would probably be useful. But you could quite trivially knock up a `ListOmitting` list wrapper class with which to implement `nMinus()` without Guava.

I can't say for sure it's not too brute-forcey, but it "feels" adequately efficient for an interview answer to me.

Comment: Note that this takes exponential time, although it is a valid solution. Adding a high-level explanation of the approach might be a good idea.

Comment: This approach is too inefficient.